# Merge 2 different columns into one in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have this MySQL table:

```
Testtag, Date, Temperature, TagName, DateTime, Value
'SGTC.0013', '2022-06-13 13:39:42', '','','',''
'SGTC.0014', '2022-06-13 13:39:42', '','SGTC.0014', '2022-07-05 13:39:42', 'Top = 103.0, Bot = -16.3'
```

Under this query:

```
SELECT * FROM chamber_data LEFT JOIN testingintern2 ON Testtag = TagName
```

What I want is sth like this:

```
Testtag, Date, Temperature
'SGTC.0013', '2022-06-13 13:39:42', ''
'SGTC.0014', '2022-06-13 13:39:42', 'Top = 103.0, Bot = -16.3'
```

This is my failed attempt so far as they said my target table a of the UPDATE is not updatable:

```
UPDATE (SELECT * FROM chamber_data LEFT JOIN testingintern2 ON Testtag = TagName)a
SET Temperature = if(Temperature='',CONCAT(Temperature,a.Value),None);
```

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: *Under this query* This query uses TWO tables. Provide BOTH tables sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts (5-7 rows per table) and desired output for this data, with explanations. Your current question is not clear.

Comment: @Akina managed to get it done by creating another table and change temperature column value to: if(Temperature='',CONCAT(Temperature,Value),Temperature) as Temperature